Copy list of distinct Datadog log query field values
I often want to copy the list of distinct values of a field (that datadog recognizes as a field) from my log query results in order to then do something, like put the list of values into a SQL WHERE clause.  The closest I have come is to get a list of top n results for the field (using "group into fields"), and then export that list as CSV file. But then I have to open the CSV file, copy it, and in the CSV file, each row has the field tag prefixed to the value, which I don't want.
What is the fastest way to get a list of the distinct values of a field into my clipboard in order to then paste them somewhere?

Viewing the field values as a table instead of "Top List" helps get rid of the tag prefix.  Then exporting that as a CSV and opening the CSV in Excel, and then using the Excel command "=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A)" is the best I have now come up with.   But there has got to be a better way.
